# issue while changing network mode from static to dhcp using java MulticastSocket in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

we have requirement to convert a device network ip mode from static to dhcp vice-versa. We are using following code to do the need.

```
MulticastSocket multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket(5353);
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(224.0.0.251);
multicastSocket.joinGroup(address);
multicastSocket.setLoopbackMode(true);
StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
command.append("SET_");
command.append(macaddress);
command.append("_<IPNetworkSettings><IPAddress>");
command.append("0.0.0.0");
command.append("</IPAddress><SubnetMask>");
command.append("x.x.x.x");
command.append("</SubnetMask><Gateway>");
command.append("x.x.x.x");
command.append("</Gateway></IPNetworkSettings>");

byte[] message = command.toString().getBytes();
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length,
            address, MULTICAST_PORT);
multicastSocket.send(packet);
byte[] buf = new byte[1000];
multicastSocket.setSoTimeout(30000);
DatagramPacket recv = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
multicastSocket.receive(recv);
String recmessage = new String(recv.getData(), US_ASCII)
                .trim();
multicastSocket.leaveGroup(address);
```

When we executed this with standalone java class, it is working fine as expected. But issue started when we have same code in my web application which is running in tomcat server. Whenever this piece of code is executed, continuously following messages will be printed in the log, not sure what is really happening in tomcat. Pls. help.

Dec 19, 2017 7:46:50 PM javax.jmdns.impl.constants.DNSRecordClass classForIndex
WARNING: Could not find record class for index: -1

Dec 19, 2017 7:46:50 PM javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming$MessageInputStream readName
SEVERE: bad domain name: possible circular name detected. Bad offset: 0xffffffff at 0x91

Dec 19, 2017 7:46:50 PM javax.jmdns.impl.constants.DNSRecordType typeForIndex
SEVERE: Could not find record type for index: -1

Dec 19, 2017 7:46:50 PM javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readQuestion
SEVERE: Could not find record type: dns[query,199.xxx.xxx.xxx:5353, length=147, id=0x0, flags=0x545f:aa, questions=935

questions:
    [DNSQuestion@19280069 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: 199.xxx.xxx.xxx255.255.255.0199.xxx.xxx.xxx??????.]

```
[DNSQuestion@5804116 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
[DNSQuestion@15634375 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
[DNSQuestion@17093854 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
[DNSQuestion@23358883 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
[DNSQuestion@30187115 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
[DNSQuestion@25734882 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
[DNSQuestion@75113 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
[DNSQuestion@15094207 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
```

Comment: You likely need to restart the JVM, i.e. Tomcat, when you change the servers IP address. That's why command-line works: It's always a fresh JVM running the code.